# adjacency matrix find if neighbores

Tags: c, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have some homewrok that looks like this:

**Question 1 ( First program adjacency.c file )**

Directed tree structure T has N nodes represented by the adjacency matrix A size NxN as follows:

`A [ u ] [ v] == TRUE` if and only if there is a directed arc from u to v in T , or in other words :
u is the parent of v. In this [example](http://s13.postimg.org/xgj2ge3on/treepic.jpg) a tree with N = 11 nodes.

We obtain the following [neighboring matrix](http://s28.postimg.org/wb2tci5wt/matrix.jpg).

The questions are:

1. You must define with #define command and / or enum the N and permanent TRUE and FALSE. Typedef should be set with a character named adj_mat defines the neighboring matrix size N.
2. You must write a function called path, which accepts as a parameter adjacency matrix A and indexes of two nodes u and v and returns TRUE if and only if there is a directed path (by directional arrow) at the intersection u v, the tree is represented by a matrix A. Otherwise it returns FALSE.

For example: path (1,8) will return TRUE. The same path (1,3). On the other hand path (3,8) will FALSE.

3. First you must write a function (main) defines a variable type adj_mat, asks the user entries for this matrix, and indexes of the two nodes. The main function function call path, to see if there is a directed path between two nodes in the data. The function to print the test result output.

have to get some help guys

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 11
enum {FALSE, TRUE};
typedef int adj_mat[N][N];

int path2(adj_mat A, int u, int v, int temp)
{
if(u == temp && A[u][v] == FALSE)
return TRUE;

if(u == temp && A[u][v] == FALSE)
return FALSE;

if(A[u][v] == FALSE)
return path2(A, u-1, v, temp);

if(A[u][v] == TRUE)
return path2(A, N, u, temp);

return FALSE;
}

int path(adj_mat A, int u, int v)
{
return path2(A, N, v, u);
}



int main()
{

int arr[N][N]= {{0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
int u;
int v;
printf("please enter two numbers \n");
scanf("%d %d", &u, &v);
printf("The answer is %d", path(arr, u, v),".");
return 0;
}
```

The problem is at the terminal when i put 1,8 it doesnt do nothing.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried, how did that fail?

Comment: edited the question. it doesnt return nothing at the terminal when i put 1, 8

Comment: If you correct the grammar, spelling and punctuation of the last line of the question, I will tell you how to fix the bug.

Comment: sorry i kind of new with programing. can you tell me what to change?

Comment: You must start with a simpler exercise. The key to writing software is to start with small, simple things that work, and build up step by step. If you try to write a large program in one go, it won't work. Try `HelloWorld`, and go from there.

Comment: actually i did that stuff i have a litlle knowledge but i must finish this exercise

Comment: As you learned when you did `HelloWorld`, to print something you must use something like a `printf` statement. Also, your algorithm for finding a path is incorrect, as you will see when you try (3,8).

Comment: Please do not change the question in response to comments. It makes them seem irrelavant.

Comment: ok thanks. edited the code but it still doesnt work. i entered the numbers at the terminal and still nothing. do you mind lookin at it again? when i compile it says too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of issues where you attempt to read beyond the end of `arr` resulting in **undefined behavior**. First when you declare an array with `N = 11` elements, your array indexes are `arr[0] - arr[10]`. Consider the following in `path`:

```
     return path2 (A, N, v, u);
```

You pass `A, N, v, u` as arguments to `path2`:

```
int path2 (adj_mat A, int u, int v, int temp)
```

Then in `path2` you attempt `A[u][v]` **wrong**, that is `A[11][v]` beyond the end of your array. (**undefined behavior**). Look at the order of the arguments. `A` is passed as `A` to `path2`, `N` is passed as `u`, `v` as `v`, and `u` as `temp`, making `u = 11`.

Next, both of the following cannot be correct:

```
    if (u == temp && A[u][v] == FALSE)
        return TRUE;

    if (u == temp && A[u][v] == FALSE)
        return FALSE;
```

What did you intend?  Also, what is this?

```
    printf("The answer is %d", path(arr, u, v),".");
```

That will not even compile (see below). When you compile, make sure you enable warnings, at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` which will help point out problems in your code.

Finally, please give the user some guidance on the range of permissible numbers, and **check the `scanf` return**:

```
    printf ("\n please enter two numbers (0-10): ");
    if (scanf (" %d %d", &u, &v) == 2)
        printf ("\n  The answer is %d.\n", path (arr, u, v));
    else
        fprintf (stderr, "error: input failure.\n");
```

I make no comment on whether your logic is correct, but you should address the foregoing before going further.

Comment: Thank you! Ill make the changes and notice you